# HTML5 video does not play mp4 video in ie11

Tags: html, internet-explorer, video

Hi i have looked at different questions containing the same problem but I have tried the different solutions with no luck I have a html5 player the code is below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body><video src="005.mp4" controls> </video></body>

</html>
```

this is a very simple player I have an apache server I have added the mime types using

```
AddType video/mp4
AddType video/ogg
AddType video/webm
AddType video/x-flv
```

the mp4 file is named 005.mp4 and it is within the root directory of the website and test1.html which has the player is also in the root directory but all i get is a html5 player and it does nothing the screen is black if I right click the play loop options are all blacked out i have tried this with multiple video formats with still the same results if i right click the page and look at view source and then click on the link for the video it starts downloading the file and then shows no file found

any ideas would be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

From MDN:

> MP4s encoded with a high profile will not run on lower end hardware, such as low end Firefox OS phones.

Make sure you are using a supported codec

[Read more about video format supports @MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Supported_media_formats)

Comment: Currently the codec that i am using is H.264 for video and acc for the audio it is only IE11 that will not play the video I dont need it to play on any other browser due to have strobe media player that currently works on all other browsers any ideas ??